# Inverse of a Lipschitz function

Tags: functional-analysis, inverse-function

If it is given that $\hat{\rho}(s)=\tilde{\rho}(s)s$. How do I prove that $s=(\tilde{\rho} \circ \hat{\rho}^{-1}(s))\hat{\rho}^{-1}(s)$ where $s \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\tilde{\rho} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$? All I can understand is that if $\hat{\rho}=(\tilde{\rho} \circ \hat{\rho}^{-1}(s))$, then the equality will be satisfied. But I don't know how to prove this.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: All I can understand is that if $\hat{\rho}=(\tilde{\rho} \circ \hat{\rho}^{-1}(s))$, then the equality will be satisfied. But I don't know how to prove this.